# Word VBA - Finding Text to Change the Style

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word document with some paragraphs formatted with style "Heading 2" that are appearing in the Table of Contents but should not be, so I wrote some macro code to find those items in a loop and change the style to "Normal" then reapply the same formatting that "Heading 2" has. One is a hyperlink that the customer wants to be All Caps. The loop should stop when a paragraph starting with the text "DESCRIPTION" is found. My code is below and ActiveSource is the current document. The problem is that it is not finding the paragraphs to be changed. Instead it seems to only be finding zero-length strings. What is the problem with my code?

```
    Dim AllCaps As Boolean
    Set FindRange = ActiveSource.Content
    With FindRange.Find
         .Style = ActiveSource.Styles("Heading 2")
         .Forward = True
         .Format = True
    End With

    Do While FindRange.Find.Execute
        With FindRange.Find
            If Left(.Text, 11) = "DESCRIPTION" Then GoTo UpdateTOC
            AllCaps = .Font.AllCaps
            .Style = ActiveSource.Styles("Normal")
            .Font.Name = "Arial"
            .Font.Size = 12
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Font.Underline = True
            If AllCaps Then .Font.AllCaps = True
        End With
    Loop
UpdateTOC:
```

Comment: "Heading 2" has the desired formatting, but the paragraphs before "DESCRIPTION" did not belong in the table of contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe a better approach to achieve what you need is to loop through all the paragraphs instead of using Find object.

```js
Public Sub FindH2()
    Dim ActiveSource As Document
    Dim prg As Paragraph
    
    Set ActiveSource = ThisDocument
    
    For Each prg In ActiveSource.Paragraphs
        If Left(prg.Range.Text, 11) = "DESCRIPTION" Then
            GoTo UpdateTOC
        End If
        If prg.Style = "Heading 2" Then
            prg.Style = "Normal"
            prg.Range.Font.Name = "Arial"
            prg.Range.Font.Size = 12
            prg.Range.Font.Bold = True
            prg.Range.Font.Underline = True
            prg.Range.Font.AllCaps = True
        End If
    Next prg
  
    
    
UpdateTOC:
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Luiz.  Your solution worked perfectly for my needs and is much easier to understand than the Find object.

Comment: Looping through the paragraphs collection is a highly inefficient way to solve the problem. It may be acceptable if there are very few paragraphs to process but using `Find` is far more efficient method and will produce the desired result far more quickly.

Answer (score 2):

- The initial `Find` locates the marker (`DESCRIPTION`).
- The subsequent `Find` locates the `heading2` style before the marker.
- Word's `Find` method "remembers" the last search settings (e.g., finding formatting with `.Format=True`). It's more reliable to specify the properties whenever you use the `Find` method.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim AllCaps As Boolean, ActiveSource As Document
    Dim FindRange As Range
    Set ActiveSource = ActiveDocument
    Set FindRange = ActiveSource.Content
    With FindRange.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "DESCRIPTION"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        If .Execute Then
            FindRange.Collapse Word.wdCollapseStart
        End If
    End With
    With FindRange.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Style = ActiveSource.Styles("Heading 2")
        .Text = ""
        .Forward = False
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        Do While .Execute
            FindRange.Style = ActiveSource.Styles("Normal")
            With FindRange.Font
                .Name = "Arial"
                .Size = 12
                .Bold = True
                .Underline = True
                .AllCaps = True
            End With
            FindRange.Collapse Word.wdCollapseStart
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code is failing because `If Left(.Text, 11) = "DESCRIPTION"` looks at `Find.Text` not the result of the Find. This can be fixed very simply:

```
Sub ReplaceHeading2()
    'variables must never be given the same name as keywords
    'Dim AllCaps As Boolean
    Dim caps As Boolean
    Dim ActiveSource As Document: Set ActiveSource = ActiveDocument
    Dim findRange As Range: Set findRange = ActiveSource.Content
    With findRange
        With .Find
            .Style = ActiveSource.Styles(wdStyleHeading2)
            .Forward = True
            .Format = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
        End With

        Do While .Find.Execute
            'if there is a match findRange is redefined to the range of the match
            If Left(.Text, 11) = "DESCRIPTION" Then
                GoTo UpdateTOC
            Else
                caps = .Font.AllCaps
                .Style = ActiveSource.Styles(wdStyleNormal)
                With .Font
                    .name = "Arial"
                    .Size = 12
                    .Bold = True
                    .Underline = True
                    .AllCaps = caps
                End With
            End If
            'collapse the range so that Find continues
            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With
UpdateTOC:
End Sub
```

Additionally, instead of applying direct formatting on top the Normal style you should create a duplicate of Heading 2 and give it a name such as "Heading 2 Non TOC". This style can then be excluded from the TOC by ensuring the the TOC is built from style names instead of outline levels. This will enable the Navigation Pane to work correctly whilst ensuring the TOC only contains the required entries.